# Nuget update when package was installed with ExcludedVersion

Tags: nuget

I am wondering whether it is possible to update package that was installed with /x flag?
For me it seems that it is not possible right now. What I mean by updating is making packages.config change with greater version of given package (done by nuget.exe update SolutionName.sln)

What is the flow of update operation? Does it look inside nupgk of actually installed package? Or it just search for version within directory name?
When version in directory name is missing is there a problem with version comparison?

I need precise explanation.

Note:
I use nuget 2.8.50224.430

I created identical thread on nuget codeplex here:
https://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/543299

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to answer my own question.
While waiting for response I decided to look at nuget.exe sources and find how is version from installed package gathered.

What I realized:
 1. Version is taken directly from packages.config.
 2. nuget update command looks for PackageName.PackageVersion.nupkg in packages directory.
 3. When wanted file does not exists, update cannot be completed (it is aborted).

I tried to change code to use directory and package name without version.
It is possible but it will be better to request another flag for that purpose.

For curious: PathResolver is created in UpdateCommand.cs

```
var pathResolver = new DefaultPackagePathResolver(sharedRepositoryFileSystem);
```

You can pass false as second argument to omit version in path concatenation.